# what are the specs of a transistor that can't be find on internet?

Tags: power-supply, transistors, specifications

[image]

It is part of a switching-mode power supply for a PC. There is a number: 1035 and a logo above this number, that seems to be a capital D. I am trying to find a replacement but it is not as easy as it should be. It is used in an arrangement of three transistors with a heatsink. Right next to a couple of big filter capacitors. The one i am looking for appears twice next to the third/first (dont know what should be the order), a SPS S18-0703 E3150 transistor (apparently, +5V stanby).

Comment: Can you post a photo of the part that clearly shows the inscriptions on it?

Answer (score 2):

No picture? Anyway, if it is in a TO-220 package, then it looks like it might be an old Fujitsu (early 1980's) NPN BJT. A "2SD1035."

```
Maximum collector power dissipation: 40 W
Maximum collector-base voltage: 150 V
Maximum collector-emitter voltage: 120 V
Maximum emitter-base voltage: 100 V (Not sure I believe this one)
Maximum collector current: 3 A
Maximum junction temperature: 150°C
Transition frequency: 1 MHz
Forward current transfer ratio (hFE), min: 50
Package: TO220
```

But that's just a guess given the D and the number you mentioned.

Comment: sorry about that... i posted a photo today. As always, thank you for commenting on this.

Comment: What does the D mean?

Comment: it is indeed a NPN, according to my measurements. With a TO-220 package. How i differentiate a BJT one?

Comment: @xag I don't honestly remember what the D means. The Japanese used 2SB and 2SD a lot in their nomenclature. I just mentally made an assumption about the likely device type on that basis and figured they cut off the 2S part of the numbering. I've seen that happen before.

Comment: @xag The "BJT" just means "bipolar junction transistor." So it just means "transistor" really. I didn't mean to imply anything more. If it is an NPN, that's all you need.

Comment: you helped me a lot... ;)

Answer (score 2):

I found almost same results

[image]

Here's a few **[equivalent or better than](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-bipolar-bjt-single/1376376?FV=1280001/cb0002e/cb0006c/cb00084/cb000ad/cb000b1/cb000b2/cb000bc/cb00178/cb80020/cb8002d/cb80036/cb80038/142c002a/142c004e/142c0051/142c0092/142c015a/142c0368/142c05e5/142c07af/142c0a1a/142c0a47/142c0bc1/142c10be/142c1da5/142c1da7/142c20e3/142c2590/142c2742/fff40015/fff80078/9300013/9300038/9300052)** parts for checking out

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems the url has an error. Have a good day. ;)

Comment: i posted a photo of the arrangment.

Comment: Sorry the filter was too long for a URL and had paste errors %20...fixed  . just rearrange BCE pins as required

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean with "jus rearrange BCE pins as required"?

Comment: MOST pins are numbered and labelled BCE for base collector emitter are the same , but I did not check everyone